# dashがうまく動きません。

Tags: python

dashがうまく動きません。
dashの例題のコードのコピペですら動きません。

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Run this app with `python app.py` and
# visit http://127.0.0.1:8050/ in your web browser.

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

# assume you have a "long-form" data frame
# see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})

fig = px.bar(df, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

実行時の表示

```
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1


c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3425: UserWarning:

To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
どうすれば、動くようにできるのでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: [Plotly Dash application not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587439)

Comment: ありがとうございます。お陰様で解決しました。